# for-loop not iterating completely

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to create an algorithm that will test if a given string is a cover-string for a list of strings. A string is a cover string for a list of strings if it contains the characters from each string from left to right order within it. For example a cover string for "house" and "hotel" would be "ahogjutsel", and an example of a non cover-string would be "ahogjsutel".

The problem i am facing is that my for loop is only completing one iteration before it returns an output. I am trying to go through each string in the list one by one, checking the index of each character to ensure the left to right order is maintained.

Any advice into how to modify my for-loop so that the algorithm goes through each character in each string would be very helpful.

public class StringProcessing {

```
//Array list to add list of strings for testing.
public static ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

public static String list1 = "abc";

public static String list2 = "def";  


//Algorithm to iterate through each word in stringList and test if it appears in the cover string
//by testing index values.
public static boolean isCover(String coverString){
    boolean isCover = false;
    stringList.add(list1);
    stringList.add(list2);
    int size = stringList.size();
    int coverSize = coverString.length();

for (int i = 0; i < (size -1) ; i ++){
        for (int j = 0; j<stringList.get(i).length(); j++){              

        if (coverString.indexOf(stringList.get(i).charAt(j)) < coverString.indexOf(stringList.get(i).charAt(j+1))){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return isCover;
        }     
}
return isCover;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

//For loop only checks if a is before b, then returns true before checking the rest of the characters and strings.
    System.out.println(StringProcessing.isCover("abfdec"));

}
}
```

Comment: If the purpose of your function is to test whether the argument is a cover string, then why are you defining the contents of `stringList` inside the function?  This will have side effects, as the value of `stringList` will live beyond each function invocation.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Perdomoff I was able to resolve this algorithm and have it function correctly, thank you for all your input.

Answer (score 3):

1. Inside your if condition, you're returning a value and this is ending your loop.
2. **EDIT** Comparing Arraylist of Strings to a String.

   EDIT 11/30/15: Letter order is considered for Deciding if word is cover string.

Changes to your methods:

```
public class StringProcessing2 {
public static ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
//Negative Case
public static String list1 = "house";
public static String list2 = "hotel";  

//Positive Case
//public static String list1 = "abc";
//public static String list2 = "def";  


public static boolean isCover(String word){
    int matchedWords = 0;
    stringList.add(list1);
    stringList.add(list2);

    for(int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++){
            if(word.contains(String.valueOf(stringList.get(i)) )){
                matchedWords++;                                
      }
}
    if(matchedWords == stringList.size()){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;           
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println(isCover("ahogjutsel"));
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, how would i then go about modifying the body of this if-statement to only return true if the expression is true for all characters in every string in stringList

Comment: @Mickd94, The string provided in the main would need to have all characters of every single  string in the arraylist of strings?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it was incredibly helpful. To be a cover string, the string provided in the main must have all characters of every string in the arraylist, maintaining the strings left to right order of characters, I have tried to show an example in the first paragraph description.

Comment: I have tested the code, the code returns true if the characters of each string are present in the cover string, however also returns true even if the characters left to right order are not maintained within the cover string, for example in the example string above, the output should be false as the left to right order of list2 and list3 is not maintained, however it returns true. I shall look into modifying the inner if statement to alter this. I must thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Mickd94, Thats a detail you didn't mention until now or on the question.

Comment: I am sorry for making this comment so vague within my description, i tried to explain this by saying 'A string is a cover string for a list of strings if it contains the characters from each string from left to right order within it.' which i realize now is a very poor effort of explaining.